# How to copy directory listed in checkedListBox to another directory?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make application which will backup folders before system reinstallation.

What I've got now, you can see above. After click on Button2 i've got "Could not find directory 'C:\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug.Desktop'."

It seems that I can't get properly full path to directory.

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(patg);
        System.IO.FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetDirectories();
        checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                string P = Path.GetFullPath(itemChecked.ToString());
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(P);
                FileSystem.CopyDirectory(P, @"P:\");
            }
    }
```

I expect that user can check boxes from list and then click on Copy(button2) which will copy folder to another location. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: What is the value of P when you get the exception? Does this Directory exist? When do you get this exception: during new DirectoryInfo, or during CopyDirectory?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse is right. Set a break-point on the line that starts with `string P = ` …  Check your values, step (over) one-line-at-a-time.  Let us know what you see.

Comment: The UserProfile folder contains many different types of directories. Some are not directories at all. Some are Reparse Points. You'll, eventually, get AccessDenied exceptions. Or the destination path will contain a list of *weird* folders. You have to manage the (more than probable) exceptions you may raise in that procedure. Also, check the type of directory you're about to copy and move on if it's something you shouldn't touch (or you're not sure how to handle).

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Value of P is "C:\Projects\[...]\bin\Debug.Desktop'."

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Also I noticed that when exe of program is inside %username% it is working normally, as I wanted.

Comment: @tgolisch I will also tag you here for new information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the resolution. It was wrong line picked from itemChecked. Right one is:

```
string P = itemChecked.FullName.ToString();
```